# how to connect Ubuntu computers to CentOS server?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I have a server, running CentOS installed.  I would like to connect other Ubuntu PCs, to the server. How do I do that? Please help me. Its urgent.

Comment: Have you tried VNC?

Comment: Have you tried SSH? You have to give us more informations about the configuration. Is the server at your home or at a computer center. And how did you set it up? And what do you want to do on your server?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to connect to a server from Ubuntu, perhaps the easiest is using the secure shell. Install `openssh-server` on the CentOS system and `openssh-client` (probably already installed) on the ubuntu systems then use `ssh username@servername`  to log onto the server, you can also have nautilus connect to the server  by using the connect to server item in the file menu. use SSH in the type dropdown, enter server name, enter username and password for account on your server.

A bit more information here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/nautilus-connect.html

See the CentOS documentation on how to install and configure openssh-server on that system. Maybe this can help:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-ssh/